# Import jar from ant ivy project to maven

Tags: java, maven, ant, ivy

I am working on an ant project and i want to use the jar created by it , in my maven project.
The ant project employs ivy to manage its dependency.

Is there any easy way to do  this if possible without changing any code on their side.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to publish artefacts generated by your ivy-based project to a maven repo so they can be resolved by the mvn-based project.

Try http://draconianoverlord.com/2010/07/18/publishing-to-maven-repos-with-ivy.html

Once the ivy-based project has published its artefacts to the mvn repo, then the mvn-based project should be able to resolve the published artefacts.

Comment: This would mean that i will have to edit the build.xml and ivy.xml. I can see ivy-ivy.xml which looks like pom.xml and the jar i want in the dist directory.  i was wondering if i could seamlessly import these to maven repo